# Using an enum as a primary key with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to use an enum as a primary key for a table? I have something like the following:

```
public enum SpecialId : uint {}

public class Thing 
{
     public SpecialId Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
```

But i get the following error on initialisation:

> An unhanded exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type 'Thing'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

This does say it needs to be a primitive (an enum is only castable to primitave) but the [EF post around enums](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx) sugguests this is possible

> Enums as keys
>
> In addition, properties of enum types can participate in the definition of primary keys, unique constraints and foreign keys, as well as take part in concurrency control checks, and have declared default values.

**Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not supported?**

On a side not I know that I could hack in this functionality using another property with not mapped on it to translate keys to enums. This is **not** the answer I am looking

Comment: have you considered adding the `Key` attribute? also what version of EF?

Comment: Yeah that doesnt help (eg `HasKey(x=>x.Id)`) EF should pick this up by convention anyway but I did try this out to see if it was the issue

Comment: Are you doing code first???

Comment: Yes but on an existing DB

Comment: enums are classes (even though they are per convention mapped to int's) and cannot be used as primary keys.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro yup but the docs seem to suggest that this isn't the case

Comment: they can be used as a PART of the primary key, not as a sole primary key.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro this is incorrect, see Pawels answer

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - the way enums work in EF is that the 'enumness' is stripped early in the stage and and they travel as underlying type down the stack. When coming from the database the process is the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work because your enum is based on uint. EF does not support unsigned integral types in general (i.e. you could use the uint type for a property) and therefore it won't work for enum properties as well.

I am personally not a big fan of enum keys. Here is just a couple of reasons:

- the values in the database can get out of sync very easily with your enum definition
- this can be broken out of box if the database generates the keys - typically database starts generating IDs from 1 but the first enum member is 0
- enum types typically have just a few constants/members. While it is possible to have values that are in the range of the enum underlying type but don't have a corresponding constant in the enum type (and EF supports this) this defeats the purpose of using the enum type

Comment: Awesome this fixes the issue. I get what you are saying about enums as keys and I totally agree. My use case is that I want an enum with a 1:* relationship with another entity in the DB. The enum table is updated at app-start off the actual enum in code and any non-existent enums are deleted. I thought about using a completely separate key for this but I don't think it actually wins me anything if I am seeding the data directly from the enum.

Comment: That's OK. As with everything - if you understand how things work and what the limitations and risks are you should be fine pushing it.

Comment: Yeah, the underlying principal is having a single canonical source for data. In this case the code is the canonical source but I want to reference that in the database in a particular way. When you try to mix canonical sources by having things that can be created in either code or application you end up with problems.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the problem is with the `enum` underlying type.

I didnt' find any information, but a quick test shows that the following types are supported

```
byte, short, int, long
```

and the following are not

```
sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong
```