# Can non-integer enums be used in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 (.NET 4.5) and noticed something strange:

A simple enum property in an entity class works fine when defined like this:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo
}

//then used in an entity class like this:
public class MyClass
{
    public TestEnum MyTestEnum { get; set; }
}
```

... but *not* when it's defined as a non-int32 type, like this:

```
public enum TestEnum : ushort
...
```

With the former, Entity Framework detects and maps the property automatically to an int column. With the latter, EF doesn't even detect that the property exists in the entity class. If I try to force it,

```
...Property(x => x.MyTestEnum).IsRequired();
```

I get the following migration error:

```
The property 'MyTestEnum' is not a declared property on type 'MyClass'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.
```

So are `ushort` enums not supported in EF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an enum as a primary key with EF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211570/using-an-enum-as-a-primary-key-with-ef)

Comment: Non integer - yes (some). Non CLS compliant - no. See the link.